# How to do performance testing for Mobile application which is dependent on web application alert notification Id?

Tags: testing, mobile, jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing

I have one scenario, In which I have to record the script for a Mobile application that is dependent on web application alert notifications.

Scenario: 1. From the Web Application I have to create one incident(Unique ID) by filling the form details same Unique ID I have to dispatch to Mobile Application from here I have to update some additional details for that Unique ID and close the Unique ID, This is the scenario how I can record the script by using Jmeter, and where I have to do Co relations?

Answer (score 0):

1. Given you start JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html) you can use it as the proxy for both the mobile and the web application
2. Most probably (in case of [HTTPS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/https) protocol) you will need to install JMeter's self-signed certificate into your browser, for "mobile" you will also need to:

- iOS - [enable full trust for root certificates](https://support.apple.com/en-nz/HT204477)
- [Android](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/360000285357-Recording-Using-Android-Devices-Recording-Using-Android-Devices) - add the following section to your [network_security_config.xml](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config) file:

  ```
  <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
      <trust-anchors> 
          <certificates src="system" />
          <certificates src="user" />
      </trust-anchors> 
  </base-config>
  ```

once done you will need to [recompile your app in debug mode](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/building-cmdline#DebugMode) and replace the release version

With regards to correlation - at least your "Unique ID" needs to be extracted from the [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler which issues the call to the web application, but there may be more dynamic values

Comment: Thanks @Dmitri , But for Web application to create the Unqui ID iam using the API to create the different ID's same ID iam trying to do coorelation for Mobile Application which is recorded in JMeter by using the HTTP script recorder and Installled the CA sertificates in Devices and started recorded in Jmeter by using the Mobile Application

Comment: here  i am having the little confusion for my mobile i have to put load upto 100 users but can we use same 30 user credentials ? or shall i create more user credentials ? if i use same credentials then it will show some user is already login,, i am using Stepping thread group.